# Like button confirmation anti-

Tags: button, facebook-like, counter, confirmation

My like button need a confirmation before the user can like a page. I have made several tests on a website under development. This causes my website to be on the «facebook blacklist».

I want to know why my counter is hidden?
Did the clickjacking protection remove the counter on the Like button?

**Url problem**:

- www.codeculture.tv/annette-tricot-machine/
- www.codeculture.tv/east-road-au-sacrilege/
- http://codeculture.tv/sam-eloi-mievreries/
- http://codeculture.tv/sepsis-plein-de-vie-2/

(**Sorry I can't post more than 2 links)

**My code**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>


  <fb:like class="facebook-share-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="200" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.codeculture.tv and it appears Facebook is scraping the URL fine.

I also went to http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.codeculture.tv and I see 16 likes for the domain.  I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary.

But when I view source of your page I get 
`<like class="facebook-share-button" href="http://codeculture.tv/annette-tricot-machine/" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="200" font=""></like>`

Notice that it is no fb:like

I also see:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

but no mention of the fb

You may want to change your like code to the HTML5 version rather than the XFBML version.

Comment: I've change to HTML5 version but I have the same problem. The four first article don't add a counter when I like it. These articles have been put online when my website was on the «blacklist».

Comment: So what's the issue?  I see 16, are you saying there should be more?

Comment: My problem is not about the default url (www.codeculture.tv) but it's about my last articles (ex:http://codeculture.tv/annette-tricot-machine/), the like button don't show counter. 

graph.facebook.com/http://codeculture.tv/annette-tricot-machine/ I have 10 likes.

Comment: Ok, you did not share that with us in the original question.  Please edit your question to reflect the URL you're having this issue with.